# if i take a queue and empty it by polling all elems from it will it be counted in extra space? or O(1) space?

Tags: queue, priority-queue, space-complexity

If I take a queue and empty it by polling all elements from it will it be counted in extra space? or O(1) space?

I took a queue but removed all elements from it by polling now I'm confused about the space I used.

Comment: What did you do with the elements removed by polling? After polling, was the storage associated with the queue freed by you or by the language/library implementation of the queue? In other words, without more info about the details of your implementation, who can say?

Comment: Usually, the size of the input is not considered in the space complexity. So if you get a queue as input and don't use any other non-constant space apart from that, then your algorithm should be of *O(1)* space. Of course, if this queue is actually doing some reallocation under the hood, then it is a different matter, as @pjs mentioned.